# JQuery: each() and this and two sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get 2 sliders running on a page. As long as I only use one slide, it's fine, but as soon as I add a second slider only the first works. Tried to solve it with each and $this, but being a novice to jquery I'm missing something.

Note: This slider is built in a way, that it takes the class like "dur-7" and uses it to calculate how long a slide is being shown. This allows in Gutenberg to add a class and such the duration for each individual slide.

Tried the concept of each and this in another example and it worked. Used console.log to see the values coming up.

https://jsfiddle.net/francis_hunger/bzvx6rac/5/

```
<html>
<div class="wp-block-group fhslide">
  <div class="wp-block-group__inner-container">
    <div class="wp-block-image dur-7"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Sequoiadendron_giganteum_at_Kenilworth_Castle.jpg"></div>
    <div class="wp-block-image dur-2"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Baum_im_Sossusvlei.jpg/2560px-Baum_im_Sossusvlei.jpg"></div>
    <div class="wp-block-image dur-9"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Buchenstamm.jpg">       </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="wp-block-group fhslide">
  <div class="wp-block-group__inner-container">   
    <div class="wp-block-image dur-20"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Baumstamm.jpg"></div>
    <div class="wp-block-image dur-20"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/54/Bl%C3%A4tterDurchRinde.jpg/2560px-Bl%C3%A4tterDurchRinde.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</div>

    </div>
    </div>


<script>
jQuery(function() {

if (jQuery('.fhslide').length!==0){

    jQuery.each(jQuery('.fhslide'), function () {

      var theImage = jQuery('.wp-block-image img',this);
      var theWidth = theImage.width(this);

      // INIT
      jQuery ('.wp-block-group__inner-container', this).children().first().addClass('active').css('opacity', '1');
      jQuery ('.wp-block-group__inner-container', this).children().last().addClass('last');


      // First Match
      var lookup = jQuery('.wp-block-group__inner-container',this).children().first().attr('class').match(/dur-[0-9]*/); // Aktuelles Element, Array          
      var durStr = '50'; // Standard
            if (!lookup == "") {
                    durStr = lookup[0].substring(4);//  We just need the first position of the array [0], then we match "dur-" and keep the seconds (as a string)
            }       
      var durInt = parseInt(durStr)*1000; // string to Milliseconds


    /****** CALL *******/
    var fh_timer = setTimeout(fh_next(this),durInt);


        /****** FH NEXT *******/

        function fh_next() {
            var a = jQuery('.active');              
            a.removeClass('active').fadeTo('slow',0).next().fadeTo('slow',1);

             // Last element
                if (a.hasClass('last')) {

            var durStr = a.siblings(":first").attr('class').match(/dur-[0-9]*/)[0].substring(4); // pick the duration of the first element (and go there)
            var durInt = parseInt(durStr)*1000;                                         a.siblings(":first").addClass('active').fadeTo('slow',1); // gehe zum ersten Element        
            } 

            // All elements
               else {

            var durStr = a.next().attr('class').match(/dur-[0-9]*/)[0].substring(4);  
            var durInt = parseInt(durStr)*1000;         
                a.next().addClass('active'); // go to next element        
               }


            /* Set the duration */
            setTimeout(fh_next, durInt);

        }// fh_next()


    // Maximum height for wrapper
    jQuery('.wp-block-group__inner-container', this).css({
        width: function() {
          return theWidth;
        },
        height: function() {
          return theImage.height();
        },
    });


    // Maximum width for wrapper  
    var totalWidth = theImage.length * theWidth;
    jQuery('figure.wp-block-image', this).css({
            width: function() {
              return totalWidth;
            }
    }); 



    });//each 

} //if

});// ready function()

</script>
</html>
```

The expected result would be, that each slider block group with the class "fhslide" works individually. Currently only the first slider runs continuously and the second slider runs once and then no any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue

You are not assigning `this` correctly:

```js
    var fh_timer = setTimeout(fh_next(this),durInt); // <---

    function fh_next() {
```

And `fh_next` does not have arguments.

### Solution

Bind `this` when calling:

```js
    var fh_timer = setTimeout(() => fh_next.call(this), durInt); // <---

    function fh_next() {
```

Could this be the problem?

Comment: Yes, this works now. Thanks a lot. So how do I know, when I have to bind something and when I don't need to bind it?

Comment: You should understand and follow the [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope). It is tricky sometimes, my short answer advice is using [arrow functions =>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) unless you really need a regular function.

Comment: Arrow functions have `this` assigned to the value where they were defined, contrary to regular functions that use the value of `this` where they are executed (unless manually binded with [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) or [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) ).